# Error while Reading from a file

Tags: c, file-io, file-descriptor

I am trying to read the contents of a file as below:

```
    int frameFD = 0;
    int readResult;
    char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];
    frameFD = open(MY_FILE, O_RDWR);
    readResult = read(MY_FILE, buff, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

the `BUFFER_SIZE` is 256.

I am getting an error saying 'error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]'
Any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read() uses the file descriptor, not the file name:

`readResult = read(frameFD , buff, BUFFER_SIZE);`